# Variable arguments in _stdcall, C++ / Inline ASM

Tags: c++, windows, programming-languages, inline-assembly

I'm in a situation where I have to mock up a _stdcall function using C++ and inline ASM, but which uses a variable number of arguments. Normally it wouldn't know how many arguments to pop from the stack when it returns control to its parent, so wouldn't work, but I'm hoping to tell it via a global variable how many params it should have and then get it to pop them off like that.

Is that actually possible? If so, can someone start me off in the right direction? I'm specifically stuck with the epilog code I would need.

My objective is to make a function which can be used as a callback for any function that requires one (like EnumWindows), so long as the user tells it at runtime how long the args list has to be. The idea is for it to integrate with some code elsewhere so it basically runs a trigger each time the callback is called and provides a link to a place where the variables that were returned can be read and viewed by the user.

Does that make sense?

Comment: The global variable will make it thread-unsafe.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't make sense, at least to me.

Comment: Can't you package the values (or pointers to the values) within an array and pass the pointer to that array plus other relevant information (types, size) instead of trying to mimic something with __stdcall it isn't made for?!

Comment: What are you trying to interface with? Most implementors view `__stdcall` and variable argument functions as incompatible precisely for the reasons that you highlight. From the documentation for [__stdcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=VS.100%29.aspx): "The callee cleans the stack, so the compiler makes vararg functions __cdecl."

Comment: Thanks all. My situation is basically that I have to make a function whose address will be passed to a function like EnumWindows() or DirectSoundEnumerate() so it gets called as a callback. But the function running it can vary, so it may be EnumWindows one moment and DirectSoundEnumerate the next. The caller is assuming my function is _stdcall, but is it not possible to just prepare a naked function that simply cleans up after itself as if it were a stdcall? I only want it to mimick _stdcall closely enough to be stable, if it's possible.

Comment: @Chris: Then you'd have to know exactly how many arguments are passed each time that function is called... in the function itself. That's simply not possible if you can't control the call-side.

Comment: @Xeo: Well it's like this: The user has a button to load a DLL into the application's process. So suppose he chooses to load DSound.dll. He looks up the reference info for DirectSoundEnumerate() and knows the callback has parameters of 4 ints. He can then set up a function from the application's GUI and tell it to expect 4 ints. That's how it's supposed to work in theory, the function should always know the size of the params it will receive - but it's the user telling it, not the caller itself. I can pass this param data through a global, but the function excepts when it returns in my epilog.

Comment: Technically you should be able to do this, but to be honest I don't see the usefulness.  You just need to cleanup the stack appropriately; see any documentation on __stdcall.

Comment: It's specifically the ASM for the cleaning up of the stack that I'm a bit hazy on. I know that, say, 'ret 10h' command should pop 4 dwords off the stack, but it seems like it only takes a number, not the value of a register, so it seems like if I want to cleanup with 'ret', I have to hardcode the param size. Any alternatives to 'ret'ing?

Comment: Just manually pop the correct number/size of parameters and 'ret' or 'ret 0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following (hacked up code):

```
static int NumberOfParameters = 0;

__declspec(naked) void GenericCallback()
{
    // prologue
    __asm push ebp
    __asm mov ebp, esp

    // TODO: do something with parameters on stack

    // manual stack unwinding for 2 parameters
    // obviously you would adjust for the appropriate number of parameters
    // (e.g. NumberOfParameters) instead of hard-coding it for 2
    // fixup frame pointer
    __asm mov eax, [ebp + 0]
    __asm mov [ebp + 8], eax // NumberOfParameters * 4 (assuming dword-sized parameters)
    // fixup return address
    __asm mov eax, [ebp + 4]
    __asm mov [ebp + 12], eax // (NumberOfParameters + 1) * 4
    // return TRUE
    __asm mov eax, 1
    // epilogue
    __asm mov esp, ebp
    __asm pop ebp
    // fixup stack pointer
    __asm add esp, 8 // NumberOfParameters * 4
    __asm ret 0
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    NumberOfParameters = 2;
    EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)GenericCallback, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't make sense. `__stdcall` doesn't allow variadic parameters, as the total size of all parameters is decorated into the function name ([from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)):

> Name-decoration convention
>
> An underscore (_) is prefixed to the name. The name is followed by the at sign (@) **followed by the number of bytes (in decimal) in the argument list**. Therefore, the function declared as `int func( int a, double b )` is decorated as follows: `_func@12`

This quote tells you how variadic `__stdcall` functions are implemented:

> The __stdcall calling convention is used to call Win32 API functions. **The callee cleans the stack, so the compiler makes vararg functions __cdecl**. Functions that use this calling convention require a function prototype.

(emphasis mine)
So, there are no `__stdcall` functions with variadic parameters, they silently get changed to `__cdecl`. :)